# Breakpoint on write to console

Tags: windows, debugging, console

I try to research in a debugger (`x32dbg`) the source of an output to the console, from a cpp program on windows `x86`. 
I tried to put a breakpoint on every instruction in `kernel32` and `kernelbase` dlls that somehow related to `console`, and yet didn't have any breakpoint hit, while a lot of output was written to the console.

Does anyone know where can I put a breakpoint in a debugger (`x32dbg` \ `windbg` etc.) in order to capture those write to console events?

Comment: this can be depended from windows version  but in modern versions - set bp on `kernelbase.ConsoleCallServerGeneric` (you need use pdb) or `ntdll.ZwDeviceIoControlFile` (export)

Comment: I work on windows 10. I set the breakpoints there on `windbg`, but it breaks there only at the beginning of the execution, while on the actual console writes it doesn't hit..

Comment: strange - exactly on win10 this api **must be called** for any console actions

Comment: begin from win7 all communication with console via `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` on `\Device\ConDrv` - so this s 100% called

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely called, but only at the beginning of the execution, and not before an actual write to the console..

Comment: it called before every write.

Comment: console use separate process for manage window - `conhost.exe` (I not say about xp here, where csrss do this) and all communication with this process is done via `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` on `\Device\ConDrv` handle - no another way

Comment: I see that it works that way when I use `WriteConsole` `WinApi` function - it breaks on ntdll!NtDeviceIoControlFile and writes the input to the console, but when I use `CRT` `wprintf` function it doesn't break there... any ideas why?

Comment: however probably `WriteFile` (kernelbase)  and then `ZwWriteFile` called (from ntdll)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for a workaround:

Couldn't you just write a little test program that does nothing else but print to stdout; and then run that in the debugger?

Meaning: just follow the execution steps of **your** program; and see where it takes you?

In other words: identify good locations for break-points by looking at what your code is doing?